# Why are multiple HTML Object Objects not displaying?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, onmouseover

I'm trying to get user-controlled display of content from 3rd party websites. In the demo setup, onmouseover of a link causes an object to be displayed, which then disappears onmouseout.

The demo works for one of the objects, and for all of them in turn if I delete the other objects, so I'm guessing the issue is about the objects interfering with each other.

I made a guess at z-index, but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the demo file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>On mouseover show object</title>
<script>
function toggleDiv(id, flagit)
{
if (flagit === 1){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Over";
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=1;
}
else {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Not over";
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=-1;
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#div1, #div2, #div3 {visibility:hidden; position:absolute; width:400px;}
#div2 {left:400px;}
#div3 {left:800px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div1',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div1',0)">Link 1</a> |
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div2',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div2',0)">Link 2</a> |
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div3',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div3',0)">Link 3</a>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>


<object id="div1" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodworking" />
<object id="div2" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironwork" />
<object id="div3" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonemasonry" />

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected it in firebug, and realized the other objects weren't being rendered at all. I made a guess that the `object` tag needed a closing `</object>`

Code fixed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>On mouseover show object</title>
<script>
function toggleDiv(id, flagit)
{
if (flagit === 1){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Over";
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=1;
}
else {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Not over";
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=-1;
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#div1, #div2, #div3 {visibility:hidden; position:absolute; width:400px;}
#div2 {left:400px;}
#div3 {left:800px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div1',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div1',0)">Link 1</a> |
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div2',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div2',0)">Link 2</a> |
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div3',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div3',0)">Link 3</a>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>


<object id="div1" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodworking" > </object>
<object id="div2" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironwork" /> </object>
<object id="div3" type="text/html" data="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonemasonry" /> </object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great and simple solution, Thank you :D